# DialogFragment default bakcground color change - Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have implemented my own Dialog by inheriting from the DialogFragment class.

I want to change the background colour of this default Dialog.

I have tried a couple of ways but none of them seem to work. 
If you see the onCreateDialog() method below, I am using a custom dialog Style:

```
public class ConfirmationDialogFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment {

String mTextMessage = "Would you like to save the message"; 
String mTextButtonOk = "Ok";
TestDialogInterface dialogInterface = null;

public void setDialogInterface(TestDialogInterface dialogInterface) {
    this.dialogInterface = dialogInterface;
}

/**
 */
public ConfirmationDialogFragment() {       
}

public void setTextMessage(String mTextMessage) {
    this.mTextMessage = mTextMessage;
}


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogCustom));
    builder.setMessage(mTextMessage)
           .setPositiveButton(mTextButtonOk, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dismiss();
               }
           })
           .setCancelable(false);                
    builder.setTitle("Loan Extension");
    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    return dialog;
}   

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    return view;        
}

public class TestDialogInterface{
    public void onYes(){}
    public void onNo(){}        
}
```

}

And the styles file look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog">        
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/red</item>                              
    </style>
</resources>
```

However the windowBackground style-item seems to have no effect. I need to change the background color of this default Dialog.

Anyone has a clue ????

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you create a custom dialog. 
for help

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

or

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-dialog-example

Comment: Thanks but thats not what i am ideally looking for. 
Is there anyway else, becoz i only need to change the color.

Answer (score 1):

Change the background color of the root view, linear layout or what ever.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me:

```
   @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Setup the layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    final View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_dialog_fragment, null);
    root.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    //Customizing the dialog features
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(root);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_gray)));
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    return dialog;
}
```

just replace sample_dialog_fragment with your layout and also R.color.light_gray with your color.
I hope it helps you.